# Simple jQuery selector

Tags: jquery-selectors

I am trying to select the surround  element when a image within the span is clicked 'remove()', but I am a little new to jQuery and can't figure out how to do it. I can't use a unique id as the element are generated dynamically.

For example:

```
<span class='type_link'> <img src='/images/deleteCross.gif' onclick='remove()' />Example</span>
```

I want to select the span when the image is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean with "select"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to hide the parent element of the image:

```
<span class='type_link'> <img src='/images/deleteCross.gif' onclick='$(this).parent().hide();' />Example</span>
```

The trick is to use "this" and the parent()-function.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) (for **selector**) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp) (for **event**)!

Also [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) provide Good example for first step in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

How about .parent() http://api.jquery.com/parent/